# Cannot find module '@env' in React Native backend folder

Tags: react-native, babeljs, dotenv

I'm attempting to set up environment variables for my project so that I can eventually deploy it safely. However, I'm getting errors when I try to set up `react-native-dotenv`.

I've followed the instructions listed in the documentation but still can't seem to get my backend to recognize `@env`.

Not sure where I'm going wrong as I'm just learning all of this.

[Backend Server Folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PgTe9.png)

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "plugins": [["module:react-native-dotenv"]]
}
```

**.env**

```
DATABASE_ACCESS = db_url
JWT_KEY = jwt_key
```

**index.js**

```
require("./models/User");
require("./models/Track");
require("@env");

const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const authRoutes = require("./routes/authRoutes");
const requireAuth = require("./middlewares/requireAuth");
const cors = require("cors");
const morgan = require("morgan");

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(authRoutes);

app.use(cors());
app.use(morgan("dev"));

const mongoUri = DATABASE_ACCESS;
mongoose.connect(mongoUri);
```

**Error**

```
Error: Cannot find module '@env'
Require stack:
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [babel-plugin-dotenv-import](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-dotenv-import)  and see, we shifted to above library from react-native-dotenv a while ago due to several issues